# how to use date formatter and compare two date string

Tags: nsdateformatter, xcode6.3, ios8.3

hii everyone i am trying to compare two date and perform some action i am stuck out hole day trying to do my best but i know i may be missing something or doing something wrong any help will kindly appreciatable.
below my code

```html
-(void)dailyCalendarViewDidSelect:(NSDate *)date
{
    //You can do any logic after the view select the date
    NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateformat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle] ;
    
   datestring1= [dateformat stringFromDate:date]; // date value by current selected date from my cal view
   NSLog(@"%@",datestring1);//output May 5, 2015
 // NSLog(@"%@",date);//output 2015-05-05 15:56:32 +0000
    datestring2 = [dateformat stringFromDate:mydate];//already fetched value
    NSLog(@"%@",datestring2);// output May 5, 2015
  // NSLog(@"%@",mydate);// output 2015-05-05 08:47:16 +0000
    if (datestring1 == datestring2) {
        
        NSLog(@"good to go");//not able to get this value
        
        
    }
    
    /*//even i try this block too
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    mydate1 = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    mydate1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:datestring1];
    NSLog(@"%@",mydate1);//otpt null
    mydate2 = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    mydate2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:datestring2];
    NSLog(@"%@",mydate2);//otpt //null
   
    if (mydate1 == mydate2) {
        
        NSLog(@"good to go");//getting value without matching condition
      

    }
      */
    
    
   
}
```

please have a look any help will be kindly helpful thanks in advance

Comment: check the date formatter that you have used . You have an issue there

Answer (score 0):

For compare two date both date must be same formate

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2(greater than current date)");
} 
else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2 (less than current date)");    
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");  
}
```

Or try this

```
if ([[date1 earlierDate:date2] isEqualToDate:date1])
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2 (less than current date)");
}
else if ([[date1 laterDate:date2] isEqualToDate:date1])
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2(greater than current date)");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");  
}
```